# Running RapidMiner Proccess from inside NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, rapidminer

I need help running a process from inside NetBeans

Hello .  I guess I have the typical question, how can I run my RapidMiner process from inside the NetBeans

I know the problem here is in the path because I read a lot about it, but no answer could really make me understand the solution

my code is

```
try {

      RapidMiner.setExecutionMode(RapidMiner.ExecutionMode.COMMAND_LINE);
      RapidMiner.init();
      Process process = new Process (new File("C:\Users\SAR\.RapidMiner\repositories\Local Repository\processes"));//the problem is here and i can't access the repository

      process.run();

} catch (IOException | XMLException | OperatorException ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

what is the exact path should i use here or using the other method

```
RepositoryLocation loc = new RepositoryLocation("//Local Repository/Users/SAR/.RapidMiner/repositories/Local Repository/processesKNN2.rmp");//i know the path here is not working right too
Process process = new RepositoryProcessLocation(loc).load(null);

process.run()
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved..if anyone is facing the same problem just replace the "retrieve" operator with "read excel" operator from inside the RapidMiner Studio